# Ruby on Raile menu page caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating applications where the menu structure is kept in a SQL database. Each user has a different menu depending on their permissions.  The menu items as well as the permissions to them change very rarely.

It is enough that the query that creates the menu structure is executed only once when logging into the application.

How and where to store this menu so as not to unnecessarily generate a lot of menu queries. Probably some kind of cache. Just where.

Please advise what topics will be helpful in solving the problem. Fragment caching, page caching, Redis?

Best regards

Comment: There's a lot of ways this could be handled--what makes the most sense depends on context we don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Like Dave says there are a lot of ways to do that, fragment caching can work and is the easiest, but I think it does not scale well, in this case, if you have a lot of users.

I would recommend a hotwire approach. Build your menu with hotwire and `data-turbo-permanent` [attribute](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/building#persisting-elements-across-page-loads), this post can help you with more ideas: https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/sidebar-or-navigation-bar-with-hotwire-turbo/1740